# Format a USB drive as unprivileged user

Tags: partition, non-root-user

I always thought unprivileged users couldn't format a USB drive, only `root` user could, so I used to mess up with `gparted` or `fdisk`.

After years or daily Linux usage I just discovered that `gnome-disk-utility` allows a user to format a USB drive without admin privileges.

I guess the user needs to belong the same group that allows mounting/unmounting (`plugdev` on Debian) and the permissions are managed the same way (you can't unmount or partition system partitions, for instance).

**What is the recommended way to format a USB drive?**

Almost every suggestion I find on the Internet involves `fdisk` or `gparted`, therefore being `root`. But even if you can log as `root` on your system, it is bad practice to be `root` when not necessary.

From this perspective,  `gnome-disk-utility` comes as a blessing.

Is there a CLI equivalent to `gnome-disk-utility` ? Not-gnome graphical equivalents?

Comment: I think `gnome-disks` also requires root privileges through [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit).

Answer (score 1):

All applications ran by normal user need extra permission to access /dev/* (that is owned by root, and other users need to be added to groups, like You said, to be able to manipulate files there according to group permissions)

To answer Your question `mkfs` is utility for formatting from commandline, for example mkfs.exfat (with arguments)

to allow users to run it without password You might for example add following entry to the bottom of /etc/sudoers

```
%sudo ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/mkfs
```

yet, I dont think You would want that (any user could format any drive...). And actually, gnome-disks asks user for a password when formatting, at least it does in my case.

Comment: OK then I shall check but I'm pretty sure it asked for a password when I tried to mess up with `/` (as a test) but not to format my USB stick. Obviously, if this assertion is false, my question is of little interest.

Comment: I'd disagree about question being of little interest. Actually I find GNU/Linux permissions quite broad - cgroups, groups, selinux, sudo, setuid's, not to mention all polkit and other GUI settings, so there might be some other items influencing/modifying default behaviour, which might be confusing, maybe not for You, but to some users.

Comment: I just checked and I confirm that `gnome-disk-utility` allows me to format my USB drive as user without entering any password. I didn't find any option to partition it differently. I can just format the existing partition. My groups are `jerome cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin scanner bluetooth`. I suspect the mechanism is similar if not the same as the one that allows members of `plugdev` to mount a USB drive partition.