# Can't use fatsort as unprivileged user anymore

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, fat, fatsort

I'm running `fatsort` on Debian Jessie. It only works when being logged in as root.

As unprivileged user:

```
fatsort /dev/sdh
openFileSystem: Permission denied!
sortFileSystem: Failed to open file system!
main: Failed to sort file system!
```

As root:

```
fatsort /dev/sdh
File system: FAT32.

Sorting directory /
```

I'm pretty sure it used to work as unprivileged user back in June 2012, but some security restrictions must have been applied since then.

`fatsort`'s Debian package maintainer [says](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851532) this is not due to `fatsort` itself but "is a general permission issue on [my] system".

I'm clueless about where to search about that.

I can live with that restriction but I would like to understand what changed. And I'd be happy if I could add some specific privilege to my user to let it use `fatsort` seamlessly.

My groups :

```
jerome cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin scanner bluetooth
```

#### Edit: groups changed in Jessie

https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups

> To manage removable drives without root privileges, you have to use the groups **cdrom** for optical drives. Optical drives can usually be mounted in according to the rules in /etc/fstab, but for other removable drives the group **plugdev** may be more practical. Starting with Debian 8 (Jessie) you need root privileges to format USB and flash memories, because their devices in /dev/ do not belong to the group **floppy** anymore.

This explains why it used to work and does not anymore.

I'm still interested in a way to let the user use FATSort without giving him all root permissions. I guess what I'm asking is move back to the situation before Jessie where users in floppy group could manage USB storage devices. There must be a good reason for that change, but I see a drawback in terms of user experience.

BTW, although I can't use FATSort like this, I can [format a USB key using gnome-disk-utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257703/format-a-usb-drive-as-unprivileged-user), so there must be ways to provide exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the user to `disk` group , as root run:

```
usermod -a -G disk USER
```

**NB** : Adding USER to `disk` group is equivalent to grant the root access.

As user run:

```
fatsort /dev/sdh
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid giving all root permissions to a simple user (bad practice). But thanks for the hint. I edited my question with further information.