# Launch a command safely with a non-privileged user without sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, security, sudo

How can I launch a command with a non-privileged user without using sudo? I need to format a USB device without root permissions. In the solutions considered ([Format a USB drive as unprivileged user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257703/format-a-usb-drive-as-unprivileged-user)), there is sudo without password, I could also set a setgid on the tool I need. What is the best solution in terms of security?

Comment: Are you setting up a system for other people? In other words, have you got root permissions, but other people have not, but must be able to format USB devices? Or do *you* need to format a USB drive in a computer, where you have no root permissions?

Answer (score 1):

In some Linux systems with Disks alias `gnome-disks` it is possible to format a USB drive and select

- MSDOS partition table or GPT
- FAT, NTFS or ext4 file system

without sudo permissions. I tested right now in Lubuntu 18.04.x LTS with `gnome-disks` from the package

```
gnome-disk-utility 3.28.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
```